# How to overcome Eventual Consistency?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, eventual-consistency

I am creating a sample .net core application 'Employee Management' using mvc. 
And I also did login and logout session for employees.

If the admin and employee tried to update record at the same time then it will be case of eventual consistency or write-write conflict.

then how should I avoid this situation?

Comment: Using modified dates, comparing the record's contents with the contents of when it was loaded, using a version number, and so on. This is too broad to answer and documented all over the web, try researching.

Comment: Thanks for reply.....you are right. I should researching....